# Python - placing Entry with relative X/Y position changes background stretch in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an application with Tkinter in Python.
I put an image as a background, and the user can resize the window's size and the image is stretched.
I added an Entry and put it in the center of the application, but now if the user resizes the window - now the background is not streched well.

Resize function:

```
def bg_resize(e):
    global heig, wid, bbg, resized_bbg, newBg, clicked
    bbg = Image.open(r"C:\backround.png")
    resized_bbg = bbg.resize((e.width, e.height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    heig = e.height
    wid = e.width
    newBg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_bbg)
    cnv.create_image(0, 0, image=newBg, anchor="nw")
```

Widget placement:

```
searchEntry = Entry(cnv, width=100).place(rely=.5, relx=.5, anchor= "center")
```

[before resize:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2l17.png)

[after resize:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbPIw.png)

Comment: Post the code on binding `bg_resize()`.  It is better to post a [mre].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.